C#でDBへAUTOINCREMENT項目を含むテーブルを追加できない
なぜテーブルごとを追加するとエラーが発生するのでしょうか？クラスの定義が間違っていますか？ご教授いただければ幸いです。
C#でのテーブル定義:
[Table(Name = "testTable")]
public class TTestTable
{
    [Column(Name = "id", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "otheritem")]
    public strint otherItem { get; set; }
}

SQLiteでのテーブル定義:
CREATE TABLE "testTable" 
(
"id"    INTEGER,
"otheritem" TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);

コード:
using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath.ToString()))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (DataContext con = new DataContext(conn))
    {
        var newTable = new TTestTable;
        newTable.otherItem = "test"
        Table<TTestTable> testTable = con.GetTable<TTestTable>();

        // InsertOnSubmit()を使用する際には追加できない
        // SubmitChanges()でエラーが発生する
        // [error near "SELECT": syntax error']
        testTable.InsertOnSubmit(newTable);
        con.SubmitChanges();

        // クエリを使用する場合は追加できる
        string query = @"
        INSERT INTO testTable (otheritem)
        VALUES (@otheritem)";
        using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, conn))
        {
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@otheritem", newTable.otherItem);
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }

        con.SubmitChanges();            
    }
    conn.Close();
}


stackoverflow の下記の投稿が同じ問題を質問しているので、この回答が参考になりそうです。 Error using System.Data.Linq.Mapping and auto incrementing the primary key in a sqlite db

IsDbGenerated = true　を削除すればよさそうです。

質問のコメントに記述した stackoverflow の投稿に対する回答によると、下記のようにすることで CREATE TABLE の定義に従って AUTOINCREMENT されるようです。
（SQLite では IsDbGenerated = true　は理解できないようなので、 int? として null で渡す必要がありそうです）
それと質問のコードはコンパイルエラーがあるので、実際にテストしたソースを貼り付けるようにしてください。
[Table(Name = "TestTable")]
public class TTestTable
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public int? id { get; set; }

    [Column]
    public string otherItem { get; set; }
}


度々で申し訳ありません。
LINQ to SQL　について下記の記事がありました
下記の記事を参考にして
1.DataContext の派生クラスを作成する。
2.その中で TTestTable EntityのInsertメソッドをオーバライドする。
3. すると SubmitChangesでTTestTableに追加する時にidを返すこともできます。
不二家: LINQ to SQL備忘録 - Blogger
■　DataContext の派生クラス
コンストラクタはそのまま記述する。
テーブル名やメソッド名の付け方は規則があるようです。
public class MyDataContext : DataContext
{
    public MyDataContext(string fileOrServerOrConnection)
        : base(fileOrServerOrConnection) { }
    public MyDataContext(IDbConnection connection)
        : base(connection) { }
    public MyDataContext(string fileOrServerOrConnection, MappingSource mapping)
        : base(fileOrServerOrConnection, mapping) { }
    public MyDataContext(IDbConnection connection, MappingSource mapping)
        : base(connection, mapping) { }

    // TTestTableエンティティのテーブル（エンティティ名の後ろにsを付ける）
    public Table<TTestTable> TTestTables;

    // TTestTableエンティティに追加する時、SubmitChanges から呼ばれるメソッド
    // メソッド名は Insert+エンティティ名とします。
    public void InsertTTestTable(TTestTable inserted)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("InsertTTestTable");
        // デフォルトのInsert処理
        //this.ExecuteDynamicInsert(inserted);

        // カスタマイズしたInsert処理
        var ids = this.ExecuteQuery<int>(@"
    INSERT INTO testTable (otheritem)
    VALUES ({0}) RETURNING id", inserted.otherItem);
        if (ids != null)
        {
            inserted.ID = ids.First();
        }
    }
}

■　using (DataContext ... 以下の行を下記のように変更します。
newTable は質問のように格納しても構いません。
using (MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext(conn))
{
    var newTable = new TTestTable() { otherItem = "test" };
    db.TTestTables.InsertOnSubmit(newTable);
    db.SubmitChanges();
    Console.WriteLine("id={0}, otherItem={1}", newTable.ID, newTable.otherItem);
}

私の開発環境
Windows11 24H2
Visual Studio Community 2022
.Net Framework 4.7.2
System.Data.SQLite 1.0.119.0
SQLite 3.36
もし、勉強でやっているのであれば、.Net8 + EF Core8の環境の方が最新なのでやりやすいと思います。
Entiy Framework Core のインストール - EF Core | Microsoft Learn
SQLite データベース プロバイダー - EF Core | Microsoft Learn
ご参考までに

１つ前の投稿では Insert はできますが、追加した id は取得できません。
Insert して追加された id を取得するには下記のように直接INSERT 文を実行するのが良さそうです。
参考にしたURL
LINQ to SQL
方法: SQL クエリを直接実行する - ADO.NET | Microsoft Learn
この中の例 2 を参考にして下記のようなSQLを実行すると Insert して id を取得できます。
var ids = con.ExecuteQuery<int>(@"
    INSERT INTO testTable (otheritem)
    VALUES ({0}) RETURNING id", newTable.otherItem);
if (ids != null)
{
    newTable.ID= ids.First();
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Insert に失敗しました");
}

期待された回答とは違いますが、SQLite では SubmitChangesでは id が更新されないようです。
